# Is an AuCl4 / Zn battery possible? (similar to CuSo4 / Zn Daniell Cell) - expense is no consideration

Tags: electrochemistry

I have been approached by an interesting fellow who collects anything made from Gold.
He has asked me to make him the Gold/Zinc equivalent of the Copper/Zinc Daniell Gravity Cell.
Would this be possible using gold chloride instead of copper sulphate?

The standard electrode potential for the

Zn2+ + 2 e− ⇌   Zn  (-0.76 V)

will be the same but the electrode potential for the gold is approx 0.6 volts higher than the Copper electrode in a regular Daniell cell.

[AuCl4]− + 3 e− ⇌   Au(s) + 4Cl− (0.93 V)

Any tips, insights, and pitfalls would be appreciated before I accidently do something dumb with this fellow's Gold.

Comment: At some current density or too high charging voltage, it may develop chlorine at charging, when diffusion or charge transfer are not fast enough.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Has anyone ever made one of these batteries that you know of?  I cannot find any reference articles...probably because no one in their right mind would want such a kooky battery.

Comment: Making a functional galvanic cell is easy. Making a good one is very difficult, regarding capacity, power, longevity, energy and power density. The critical factor is making as big active electrode surface as possible. For rechargable ones, the electrolyte and electrode material must endure as many cycles as possible without mechanical or chemical deterioration.

Comment: From what I gather, this fellow is interested in having this battery form gold metal crystals in the same manner as the Daniell Cell he saw in my lab grows copper metal crystals.  That should make the battery simpler since no recharging will be needed.  If I can get it to blink an LED through a step up circuit that would definitely amuse him so ideally... 1 V @ 20 mA.